# SQLite3 - Extract street name from address string

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite3 with column "address" like

```
row1: "bakerstr 42, city" 
row2: "bakerstr 22, zip"
row3: "poststr 42a, location"
row4: "Maple drive"
```

How could I extract just the streetname from the address column

Expected result:

```
bakerstr
poststr 
Maple drive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (address varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('bakerstr 42, city')
insert into @t values ('poststr 42a, location')
insert into @t values ('Maple drive')


select substring(address,1,case when PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',address) = 0 then len (address) else PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',address)-2 end)  from @t
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
SQLite3 tells me: `no such function: PATINDEX`
I assume this is not a valid SQLite3-Syntax.